# Creating a database using mvc model entity framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I want to create a database using model enitity framework. I do have a snap with me
can anybody suggest me?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly and if you are looking at a start point for this, I would suggest going through the following tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

> The Entity Framework can automatically create (or drop and re-create) a database for you when the application runs. You can specify that this should be done every time your application runs or only when the model is out of sync with the existing database. You can also write a class that includes a method that the Entity Framework automatically calls after creating the database in order to populate it with test data. In this section you'll specify that the database should be dropped and re-created whenever the model changes.